# carousel problems

Tags: android

I'm using carousel code Imade 5 classes and usd same as http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel
but when i run the program wic i made it's give me and give me error that R.layout.main 
main:main canot be reslt or not field ... how can i solve this??
and i have another problem in Carousle class:

```
int min = arr.getInteger(R.styleable.Carousel_minQuantity, MIN_QUANTITY);
```

on styleabl cannot be result or faild plz i need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import R like this:
import pakageName.R such as(com.mm.name.R);